# In the Schengen application form, do I need to list the entry permit for the final country of destination if I go to non-Schengen country after?

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas, applications

There's a particular field which asks for final country of destination visa information if applicable. I read online that it only counts in case of transit. Since I am spending 8 days in the Schengen area starting with Germany, then going to Dubai, spend 3 weeks there with family, which I am yet to apply for a visa for(I need one), and then back to the US on my F1 visa. What do I fill, if at all I fill anything? I am travelling by air entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be Field 28 of the **Application for Schengen Visa**

- **Entry permit for the final country of destination, where applicable**

The handbook implies that destination visas should be checked to verify that a onward ticket can be undertaken

- so the text at **6.6.1** could also apply for a non-transit visa

For the Cousulate, your **final** destination is returning to the United States

- so the present lack of a Dubai visa

is probably not of great importance, since if that is denied you can still return to the United States.

---

The Annex to Commission Decision No C(2010) 1620 establishing the Handbook for the processing of visa applications and the modification of issued visas

- 14.5.2019

> 5.2.1 Non-exhaustive list of supporting documents regarding the purpose of the journey,
>   the accommodation and the assessment of the applicant’s intention to leave the territory
>   of the Member States that may be requested by the consulate
>
> (3) for journeys undertaken for the purposes of tourism or for private reasons:
>   ...
>
> > **in the case of transit: visa or other entry permit for the third country of destination**;
> >     tickets for onward journey;
>
> 6.6.1 How to verify the sufficient means for leaving the territory of the Member States?
>   The consulate should check the following:
>   ...
>
> > – if the applicant has presented an onward ticket, it should be checked whether he is **in possession of a visa** or any other document allowing the entry into the intended country of destination.

Comment: So if you don't mind me asking, what exactly would I fill in that field?

Comment: @Ishwar Since the F1 is more a residence permit than a visa and no Dubai visa exists yet, I would say nothing.